# When is a generic method appropriate and when it is not?

Tags: java, generics, collections, generic-method

I am trying to have a deep understanding on when a generic method is to be written versus a non-generic method. Both the Collection interface as well as the Collections helper class  has the `addAll()` method albeit with different signatures and the former one **is not** a *generic* method whereas the later one **is**  a generic method:

The signature of `addAll()` in Collection:

```
  boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c);
```

The signature of `addAll()` in Collections:

```
 @SafeVarargs
    public static <T> boolean addAll(Collection<? super T> c, T... elements){}
```

So as a general rule when is it appropriate to write a generic vs a non-generic method?

Edit: My understanding of the term generic method is that it will have a type parameter or comma separated list of type parameters in angle brackets before the return type of the the method. Correct me if the definition is not correct.

Comment: Both are generic methods, what's wrong?

Comment: @Kayaman He meant that the former is a method of a generic class whereas the lateer is simply a gernric method

Comment: The former is a generic **instance** method, the latter is a generic **static** method. Both methods are generic.

Comment: @Kayaman Look at the signature, the stuff in angle bracket before the return type is missing in the first snippet.

Comment: Yes, a static method needs the extra parameter, because it doesn't have the type from the enclosing class (like an instance method has).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between bounded wildcard and type parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750273/what-is-the-difference-between-bounded-wildcard-and-type-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use only generic methods.If you use generic methods/containers your code is type safe. Collection and Collections classes keep some "non-generic" methods only to provide backwards compability. You could read "Effective Java - second edition"(written by Joshua Bloch), item 23 "Don’t use raw types in new code" and you will understand why it is better to use generic methods.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ,you need to understand that `Collections` is simply a concrete class with static methods for manipulating `Collection` interface instances.Therefore,the class Collections is not generic but it has a number of generic methods to tackle the parameters of static methods which may themselves be generic

Practically ,speaking both are generic methods.The former one is a generic method of a generic class whereas the latter is simply a generic method without the class being generic as a whole.

The super keyword in the argument of the 2nd case is simply to allow elements to be added to it.If it had been a collection of any kind which extends a particular type,then you would not have been able to add an element