# Difference between generic types and wildcards extending a type for parameters to a method

Tags: java, generics

When I try to set a parameter as extending number using wildcards as shown in the code below -

```
import java.util.*;

class Try {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        List <Integer>a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add(1);
        a.add(2);
        a.add(3);
        System.out.println(foo(a));
    }

    public static double foo(List<? extends Number> list) {
        double x = 0.0;
        for (Object e : list)
            x += (Integer) e;
        return x;
    }
}
```

It compiles fine.
However, If i do the same using a generic type, as shown here -

```
import java.util.*;

class Try {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        List <Integer>a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add(1);
        a.add(2);
        a.add(3);
        System.out.println(foo(a));
    }

    public static <T extends Number> double foo(List<T extends Number> list) {
        double x = 0.0;
        for (Object e : list)
            x += (Integer) e;
        return x;
    }
}
```

I get the following syntax error -

```
Try.java:12: error: > expected
    public static <T extends Number> double foo(List<T extends Number> list) {
                                                       ^
Try.java:12: error: ')' expected
    public static <T extends Number> double foo(List<T extends Number> list) {
                                                              ^
Try.java:12: error: ';' expected
    public static <T extends Number> double foo(List<T extends Number> list) {
                                                                     ^
Try.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
    public static <T extends Number> double foo(List<T extends Number> list) {
                                                                           ^
4 errors
```

Why does the second case give me an error? What is the difference between generics and wildcards in this case?

Comment: "It compiles fine" but doesn't isn't type safe. Try calling `foo(Array.asList(0.0))`. That also compiles fine, but fails at runtime.

Comment: Use `List<T>` instead. It's already a bounded type variable. (But this doesn't make it type safe though).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between bounded wildcard and type parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750273/what-is-the-difference-between-bounded-wildcard-and-type-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is invalid syntax. This is what you intended:

```
public static <T extends Number> double foo(List<T> list) {
```

That is, the `extends` belongs to the type token definition, not the type declaration in the method parameter list.

Comment: Why isn't wildcards type-safe considering that ? extends Number, thus guaranteeing that all types passed are subtypes of Number. Does using generics do something more than this?

Comment: With the wildcards version, you could pass in a list that has a mixture of subtypes of Number in it, that is, not homogenous. With three generic version there can be only homogenous objects

Comment: "The main difference between this and your first wildcard version is that this is type-safe." There's no difference between this and the first version, because `T` is not used beyond this parameter declaration. This version would allow you to use `T` as the type of the enhanced for loop variable, for example. But even then, there is no type safety advantage.

Comment: This is completely identical to the first wildcard version. It cannot be "type-safe" if the other one isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in your second piece of code you meant this:

```
public static <T extends Number> double foo(List<T> list)
```

There is no difference between the two declarations. Any type that can be passed to one function signature can be passed to the other, and vice versa. Every possible type `List<T>` where `T` is a non-strict subtype of `Number`, is a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`. And `List<? extends Number>` can be captured into `List<T>` with `T extends Number`. So the two are completely equivalent.